# Does Konami have this?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

Does Konami have e-mail or whatever to fan-cards for Yu-gi-oh? I'm know they not take fan-cards from net, but maybe they have the special e-mail for cards or some contests. I just saw on Yu-gi-oh wiki that was some kind of competition or something like that, where fans drew their cards and some of them were even added to the anime later

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be addressed to Konami customer support.

Comment: I'm be glad if you say me how I can contact with them

Comment: What happens if you Google "Konami customer support"?

Answer (score 3):

From a very general standpoint, most creators (including game publishers, authors, etc) do not accept unsolicited fan submissions. The main reason for this is liability - if I send Konami a fan card, and some time later Konami releases a card that is very similar, then I might think they stole my idea and try to get them to give me credit. In reality it's likely that nobody involved in designing that card even saw my email, but proving it could result in a lot of painful legal proceedings where no-one benefits other than the lawyers.

In fact, Konami has a very similar answer to this in their FAQ: [Can I submit a new game idea?](https://eu-support.konami.com/hc/en-gb/articles/115011932907-Can-I-submit-a-new-game-idea-)

It's possible that they could hold a competition to design a card, but if they choose to then it will (a) be heavily promoted, and (b) have very clear guidelines on entries that boil down to "once you send us an idea, we own everything about it and can do whatever we want with it". On the one hand, this can be seen as a nasty corporate move to get free access to people's creative work, but on the other hand it ensures that they don't have to worry about those legal proceedings.